# KeyPress image should zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my link http://fiddle.jshell.net/ajs2a/4/

I want this to happen on keyPress.

My Javascript code that I have tried for 2 images, I have used transform scale.

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var image2 = document.getElementById("img2");
document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

function doKeyDown(e){

    //====================
    //  THE W KEY
    //====================
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        image1.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(6);');
        image2.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1);');
    }

    //====================
    //  THE X KEY
    //====================
    if (e.keyCode == 88) {
        image1.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1);');
        image2.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(6);');
    }
}
```

This code is bad. When I use this, it is not as smooth as fiddle demo i have shown.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @BenM: The fiddle is not for the code shown above. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @BenM: `"This code is bad. When I use this, it is not as smooth as fiddle demo i have shown."`

Comment: @BenM: It is not 'He'. It is 'She'. When she says the code is not same as the fiddle demo, there is only one code part and only one demo in the question, she clearly means the code is different than the one in the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your `#img1`:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
```

I simplified your JS somewhat:

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("img1");
document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);

function doKeyDown(e){

    // W Key:
    if(e.keyCode == 87) 
    {
        image1.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(6);');
    }

    // K Key:
    if(e.keyCode == 88) 
    {
        image1.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1);');
    }
}
```

This is working exactly as expected.

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ajs2a/9/)

Comment: Which if you check the jsFiddle demo posted, it does?

Comment: It didn't when you first posted the answer.

Comment: Correct. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: So when I various images I need to scale back each one before zooming?

Comment: If that's the functionality you want, yes. It won't happen automatically.

Comment: true...! I see that when I zoom first image it is zooming under 2nd image. No matter which ever image i zoom, I want to bring to the front. Like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ga7Er/)

Comment: @Archana http://fiddle.jshell.net/ajs2a/7/ the link in my answer is not what you want?

Comment: @Sarath I have got what you have posted. But overlapp is what I want at the center of the screen.

Comment: @Archana that's another question entirely. If you wish to achieve that, you need to manipulate the positioning of the element in addition to the scaling behaviour.

Comment: Yes ok. I will post a  new question.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Archana .. ok that you can just add some z-index and translate() , check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/ajs2a/10/

Answer (score 3):

Change the css transition

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease,height 0.6s ease,left 0.6s ease,top 0.6s ease;
```

to

```
   -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
```

and corrected the changes the css class to ids.

If you want to centered make it like

```
 image1.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(2) translate(0,50px);z-index:1');
 image2.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:scale(1) translate(0,0);z-index:0');
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ajs2a/10/)</kbd>**

Comment: added the link , check now

Comment: I dont understand how this is working. You have used `-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;` in CSS, but no change in JS, and how come on key press its working. without any change in JS? not working for second image(while the first image should go back to its previous size).

Comment: Between your links he has changed the Javascript to transform the image, you had the Javascript applying the transition without a transform.

Comment: I mean I want to zoom it when i press a particular key for a particular image.

Comment: @Archana check the undeleted answer.

Comment: @Archana you have few erroes in ids and class and you specify transion for width,height, etc

Comment: @Archana i change the transition to all means any change in css props will make it with effect `.6 ease`